# For Go, ioutil.ReadAll / ioutil.ReadFile / ioutil.ReadDir deprecated

Tags: go

Starting from Go 1.16, `ioutil.ReadAll`, `ioutil.ReadFile` and `ioutil.ReadDir` are deprecated, as the package `io/ioutil` is deprecated.

What other stdlib packages provide the same functionality?

Comment: See the [ioutil package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/io/ioutil).  The documentation for each function refers to the new function.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

```
ioutil.ReadAll -> io.ReadAll
ioutil.ReadFile -> os.ReadFile
ioutil.ReadDir -> os.ReadDir
// others
ioutil.NopCloser -> io.NopCloser
ioutil.TempDir -> os.MkdirTemp
ioutil.TempFile -> os.CreateTemp
ioutil.WriteFile -> os.WriteFile
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm using `go version go1.20.3`

Getting error

> "io/ioutil" has been deprecated since Go 1.19: As of Go 1.16

just update

> **import "io"**

It works!

ref - https://pkg.go.dev/io